# What is the syntax for declaring an index variable in a Delphi 2007 Pascal Initialization block?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal

I need to initialize and array in a Delphi Initialization block.

It appears that you cannot use a var block in an initialize block because this won't compile:

```
initialization
var
idx : Integer;
begin
    for idx := 0 to length(LastState)-1 do begin
        LastState[idx] := $FFFF;
    end;
end;
```

(The first compilation error complains about *var*):

> ([DCC Error] ScheAutoInfRb2.pas(6898): E2029 Statement expected but
>   'VAR' found)

This does not compile either (because idx is not declared):

```
initialization

    for idx := 0 to length(Last_Pro2State)-1 do begin
        Last_Pro2State[idx] := $FFFF;
    end;
```

> [DCC Error] ScheAutoInfRb2.pas(6899): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'idx'

I know that I can declare an indexer in the main unit declaration, but that has a couple of disadvantages:

1. The declaration of the indexer is separated from its use but the
   implementation section (which can be hundreds of lines away), and
2. The scope of the indexer includes all the functions and procedures
   in the Implementation section.

Comment: Declare a procedure which initializes the array immediately above the initialization section and call it from there.

Comment: And declare idx in the same place you declared LastState.

Comment: initialization replaces begin, and variable declaration is before begin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't.

The usual way to do this is to write a procedure that you then call from the `initialization` section:

```
procedure InitLastStateArray;
var
  idx : Integer;
begin
  for idx := 0 to length(LastState)-1 do begin
    LastState[idx] := $FFFF;
  end;
end;

initialization
  IntLastStateArray;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know that I can declare an indexer in the main unit declaration, but that has a couple of disavantages:

Both of the disadvantages you mention can be avoided by declaring it in the `implementation` section right at the end, just above the `initialization` section. There's no need or benefit in having it in your `interface` section, nor in having it at the top of the `implementation` section: you're right about the disadvantages you mention, it unnecessarily increases the scope of the variable and moves its declaration away from where it's used,  and there are no advantages to counter that. You only need to put variables in the `interface` section if you want other units to be able to access those variables.

```
var
  idx : Integer;
initialization
  for idx := 0 to length(LastState)-1 do
    LastState[idx] := $FFFF;
end.
```

That's the best you can get, there's no way in D7 to get a variable declaration inside the `initialization` block, but for completeness, in later versions of Delphi you should be able to use an anonymous procedure, which can be defined completely (including local variables) inside an expression pretty much anywhere.

---

While technically this makes `idx` as a global variable, Rob Kennedy notes that as long as it's only used inside the `initialization` block, the compiler will treat it as if it's a variable local to that block. When experimenting, I found this isn't entirely true, I was able to find counterexamples when taking the variable's address for instance, but for practical purposes it should be close enough. Besides, for a block that's only executed once, there's little difference between a local variable and a global otherwise inaccessible variable.

Comment: Global variable is a bad idea. Put the code in a function. No cause for anon methods here either.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not interested in religious arguments. I know when global variables cause maintenance headaches. I avoid them when they do so. I don't avoid them when they don't do so.

Comment: It's a mistake to have a variable whose life extends the entire lifetime of the program that is only used at startup. I don't believe that's religion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, it's not a mistake, it's a matter of picking the lesser evil. That's a matter of opinion in which we disagree. That's okay.

Comment: Where is the evil of limiting the lifetime of variables. There's no evil in using a procedure here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sure there is. If it's obvious that the code only makes sense to ever call once, and it's extracted into a separate method, it takes more effort to verify that it's only called once and only from the initialization section. Yeah, it's a minor issue. So is the global variable.

Comment: Private scope variable is perfectly fine for this case.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Perhaps you missed the point. `initialization` blocks can't have private scope variables.

Comment: [Unit-scope variables that are used only in the initialization section are treated by the compiler like local variables.](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=10688) One way to ensure that a unit-scoped variable is only used by the initialization section is to declare it immediately above that section, in which case it's visually similar to declaring a local variable immediately above the `begin` keyword of an ordinary function. (Once there's also a finalization section, then it's harder to argue the index variable is really "local" since it's available to two separate blocks.)

Comment: @hvd, no, there's no syntax for declarations there. Two scope levels are available at this point, correct one is unit's private scope.

Comment: @FreeConsulting In other words, exactly what I put in my answer?

Comment: Yes. Since OP appears to be confused about syntax, I'd suggest you to add declarations/statements explanation.

Comment: @RobKennedy Thanks for the info, I wasn't aware of that. It turns out it's not entirely true, but it's close enough, I included a note about that.